# Using \opening in Letter Document Class

Tags: letters

I am using `\documentclass[12pt, letterpaper]{letter}`

The following code prints the `Sindku, Viċi Sindku, u Kunsilliera, Ħaż-Żabbar` twice.  I wonder what each is actually supposed to do?  Would one use `\opening{Sindku, Viċi Sindku, u Kunsilliera, Ħaż-Żabbar}`and have `\begin{letter}{}`?  What text is customarily used within `\begin{letter}`?

```
\documentclass[12pt, letterpaper]{letter}

\begin{document}

\begin{letter}{Sindku, Viċi Sindku, u Kunsilliera, Ħaż-Żabbar}

  \opening{Sindku, Viċi Sindku, u Kunsilliera, Ħaż-Żabbar}

  Text

  \closing{Yours Sincerely,}
  \signature{Christopher Dimech}

\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

Comment: And keeping  `\begin{letter}`  empty with  `\begin{letter}{}`.

Comment: Please provide a full but minimal example, so we know exactly what you are doing.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\opening` is for something like “Dear Sirs”. The addressee is to be the argument to `\begin{letter}`

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{letter}

\signature{Randy}

\begin{document}

\begin{letter}{Sindku,\\ Viċi Sindku,\\ u Kunsilliera \\[1ex] Ħaż-Żabbar}

\opening{Gheziez Sinjuri}

Billi l-għarfien tad-diniità proprja tal-membri kollha tal-familja 
umana u tad-drittijiet tagħhom ugwali li ma jistgħux jitteħdulhom 
hu ssies tal-ħelsien, tal-ħaqq u tal-paċi fid-dinja,

Billi t-tkasbir u ż-żebliħ tal-jeddijiet tal-bniedem ġabu magħhom 
għemejjel kiefra li weġghu l-kuxjenza ta' l-umanitŕ, u l-miġja ta' 
dinja fejn il-bnedmin ikunu ħielsa li jitkellmu u jemmnu, me˙lusa 
mill-biża' u mill-miżerja, kienet proklamata bħala l-ogħla xewqa 
tal-bniedem,

\closing{Dejjem tiegħek}

\encl{https://www.ohchr.org/en/human-rights/universal-declaration/translations/maltese}

\end{letter}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I got the opening and closing phrases from Google Translate. Compile with XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX. However, there's no support (yet) for Maltese neither with `babel` nor with `polyglossia`.

Comment: I suppose that I would have to do the maltese one.

Comment: @Randy The most difficult part is getting hyphenation patterns right. But maybe it's not that hard if the hyphenation rules aren't too complex.